# Spring Data Neo4j 6 Relationship.UNDIRECTED

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

I'm upgrading my code to use Spring Data Neo4j 6.1.2

With an earlier version, I was able to set the relationship direction as `UNIDIRECTED`:

```
@Relationship(type = RelatedEntity.TYPE, direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
    private Set<RelatedEntity> relatedEntities = new HashSet<>();
```

With this, I could get mutual relationships from either node. I assume this was internally ignoring the direction in the generated cypher code.

In the latest version, I only see `INCOMING` and `OUTGOING`. Is there a way I can replicate the previous behaviour or would I have to write custom queries?

Answer (score 0):

There is no replacement for the `UNDIRECTED` relationship.
Spring Data Neo4j 6 requires you to specify the very same direction that you have in your data. If you need a bidirectional definition, e.g.

`(user1)-[knows]->(user2)-[knows]->(user1)`

you would have to add the relationship as `INCOMING` and `OUTGOING` to the entity.

Comment: Ok thanks, but what if we wanted to only create one relationship and ignore the relationship direction to query  (e.g. an interest is related to another interest and direction is not important). Would I have to write a cypher query to retrieve the results or can I customise a find query?

Comment: You cannot do this with only one relationship in the model. Even the result of a custom Cypher query would only map the relationships that match the defined directions.

Comment: That’s going to be a problem for us with our existing models. We may have to stick with the previous version.

Comment: Hi meistermeier, is there any possibility to submit a feature  request for this functionality. From what I understand this is still available to do in Neo4j so just wanted to understand why this was removed.

Comment: Neo4j only provides directed relationships. Neo4j-OGM just does ignore this direction. We decided with SDN 6 to not support this anymore because the model would not match  the stored data.